# Is this a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $R^2$ with the following non-standard addition operation ⊕:
$(a,b)⊕(c,d) = (a+d,b+c)$.

Scalar multiplication is defined in the usual way. Is this a vector space?

Do we need to take into consideration that the pairs are ordered? If so, will the answer be that: The Set is not a vector space since the non-standard addition operation affects the commutativity property of the set.

Comment: But $\oplus$ is conmutative.

Comment: You can test all of the normal vector space axioms. This looks like addition **is** commutative, so you should check the others.

Comment: (1+1)(1,0) = 1*(1,0)+1*(1,0) = (1,0)+(1,0) = (0,0) yet 2*(1,0) = (2,0) (assuming I have correctly interpreted the product when you "the usual way" for the multiplication. Assuming I have interpreted it correctly, this would imply this is not a vector space as in a vector space we need (a+b)v = av+bv for scalars a,b and vector v

Comment: I am sorry I mistyped the question

Comment: Given that ⊕ is commutative I already know what to do. Thank you guys !

Comment: With the edit., you have $(a,b)\oplus (c,d)=(a+d,b+c)$, but $(c,d)\oplus (a,b) = (b+c,a+d)$.  This new $\oplus$ after the edit is *not* commutative.  "*Do we need to take into consideration that the pairs are ordered?*"  Yes, obviously, since the elements of $\Bbb R^2$ *are* ordered.  The element $(1,0)$ is not the same as the element $(0,1)$.

Comment: Variant on @mathew's comment (before edit of question?) $(1+1)(1,0) = 1(1,0) \oplus 1(1,0) = (1,1)$. But $2*(1,0) = (2,0)$....

Comment: @JMoravitz that is what I thought when doing the exercise but since it is my first time to see ⊕ I was not sure of its properties. Thank you.

Comment: The whole point about using a symbol like oplus is that it is a symbol that we *don't* know the properties of except those the problem tells us of.  And the properties it does tell us of are enough to finish the problem after a little thought.  The next time you see an oplus it will likely be in reference to something completely different than how it was used here, representing an entirely different operation in a different space that has nothing to do with this problem.